# windows service SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, winapi, segmentation-fault

My Windows service gives SIGSEGV at the end of ServiceMain function.

Here's the code:

Start:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    SrvName[16]=0;
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY servicetable[]=
    {
        {strServiceName,(LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain},
        {NULL,NULL}
    };
    BOOL success;
    success=StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(servicetable);
assert(success!=0);
    return(0);
}
```

Service start:

```
void ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv)
{

    BOOL success;
    nServiceStatusHandle=RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(strServiceName,
        (LPHANDLER_FUNCTION_EX)ServiceCtrlHandler, NULL);
assert(nServiceStatusHandle!=0);
success=UpdateServiceStatus(SERVICE_START_PENDING,NO_ERROR,0,1,20000);
assert(success!=0);
killServiceEvent=CreateEvent(0,TRUE,FALSE,0);
assert(killServiceEvent!=NULL);

success=UpdateServiceStatus(SERVICE_START_PENDING,NO_ERROR,0,2,10000);
assert(success!=0);

nServiceCurrentStatus=SERVICE_RUNNING;
success=UpdateServiceStatus(SERVICE_RUNNING,NO_ERROR,0,0,0);
assert(success!=0);

WaitForSingleObject(killServiceEvent,INFINITE);
CloseHandle(killServiceEvent);

UpdateServiceStatus(SERVICE_STOPPED,NO_ERROR,0,0,0);
return;
}///2x SIGSEGV here
```

Status update function:

```
BOOL UpdateServiceStatus(DWORD dwCurrentState, DWORD dwWin32ExitCode,
        DWORD dwServiceSpecificExitCode, DWORD dwCheckPoint,
                 DWORD dwWaitHint)
 {
BOOL success;
SERVICE_STATUS nServiceStatus;
nServiceStatus.dwServiceType=SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
nServiceStatus.dwCurrentState=dwCurrentState;
if(dwCurrentState==SERVICE_START_PENDING)
{
    nServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted=0;
}
else
{
    nServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted=SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP
        |SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;
}
if(dwServiceSpecificExitCode==0)
{
    nServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode=dwWin32ExitCode;
}
else
{
    nServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode=ERROR_SERVICE_SPECIFIC_ERROR;
}
nServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode=dwServiceSpecificExitCode;
nServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint=dwCheckPoint;
nServiceStatus.dwWaitHint=dwWaitHint;

success=SetServiceStatus(nServiceStatusHandle,&nServiceStatus);

    return success;
}
```

SCM messages handler:

```
void ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD nControlCode,DWORD dwEventType,
LPVOID lpEventData,LPVOID lpContext)
{
switch(nControlCode)
{
case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:
case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
    nServiceCurrentStatus=SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
    UpdateServiceStatus(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING,NO_ERROR,0,1,10000);
    SetEvent(killServiceEvent);
    return;
default:
    break;
}
UpdateServiceStatus(nServiceCurrentStatus,NO_ERROR,0,0,0);
return;
}
```

So,i've got 2 sigsegv at the end of ServiceMain(): 
"Service.exe caused an Access Violation at location 00000000 Reading from location 00000000."
Registers:

```
eax=00000000 ebx=00617d60 ecx=75bd76ba edx=00600174 esi=00000001 edi=00000000
eip=00000000 esp=010eff8c ebp=00617d70 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010246

AddrPC   Params
00000000 00617D60 010EFFD4 77A437EB
7765ED5C 00617D60 70866618 00000000 kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk
77A437EB 77B47587 00617D60 00000000 ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain
77A437BE 77B47587 00617D60 00000000 ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain
```

I'm using Code::Blocks with MinGW, Win7 32bit pro.

Have you got any ideas about it?

Comment: Don't cast `ServiceMain`. Fix the actual signature by putting the correct calling convention. AFAIK, whatever is using your `SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY` is expecting `ServiceMain` to clean the stack, but `ServiceMain` is expecting the aforementioned function to clean it. Sounds like a problem.

Comment: When making a Windows service, it's always good to have a way of running it like a normal non-service program. That way it will be much easier to debug, as you can actually run it in a debugger.

Comment: I'll second the don't cast it advice.  If you have to cast it then it isn't declared correctly.

Comment: Chris, thank you man! It was stupid of me to forget about calling convention. Now it's all right.

Comment: Can I just be pedantic and point out that there's no such thing as SIGSEGV on Windows? There are access violations, which are just Windows' name for what Unix calls a segmentation fault, but they are not reported via POSIX signals, and so, you'd be hard pressed to find a SIGSEGV anywhere in your Windows service, no matter how it misbehaves. ;) This message was brought to you by the committee for not using the wrong terminology. ;)

Answer (score 1):

All of your service handlers are missing the `WINAPI` (`__stdcall`) calling convention, and your `HandlerEx` is also missing a return value.  These mistakes are causing mismanagement of the call stack.

Fix your declarations, and get rid of the type-casts.  The compiler would have issued errors about the incorrect declarations, but you forced it to ignore them and accept your bad code.

```
SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY servicetable[]=
{
    {strServiceName, &ServiceMain},
    {NULL,NULL}
};
```

```
void WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv)
{
    ...
    nServiceStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(..., &ServiceCtrlHandler, ...);
    ...
}
```

```
DWORD WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD dwControl, DWORD dwEventType, LPVOID lpEventData, LPVOID lpContext)
{
    switch(dwControl)
    {
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
            ...
            return NO_ERROR;

        case SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE:
            ...
            return NO_ERROR;

        default:
            return ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
    }
}
```